# Get Parent From gtk-rs CompositeTemplate

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

How do I get the parent of a CompositeTemplate in gtk-rs?

```
    #[derive(Debug, Default, gtk::CompositeTemplate)]
    #[template(resource = "/org/bil4x4/gnote/tree_view")]
    pub struct GnoteTreeView {
        #[template_child]
        pub tree_store: TemplateChild<gtk::TreeStore>,

        pub add_note_visible: Cell<bool>,
        pub add_folder_visible: Cell<bool>,
        pub remove_item_visible: Cell<bool>,
    }

    #[glib::object_subclass]
    impl ObjectSubclass for GnoteTreeView {
        const NAME: &'static str = "GnoteTreeView";
        type Type = super::GnoteTreeView;
        type ParentType = gtk::TreeView;

        fn class_init(klass: &mut Self::Class) {

            klass.bind_template();
            klass.bind_template_instance_callbacks();
        }

        fn instance_init(obj: &glib::subclass::InitializingObject<Self>) {
            obj.init_template();
        }
```

so in the `impl GnoteTreeView` section I am not sure how to get the `gtk::TreeView`. I am pretty sure it is something like `self.imp().?`

I have tried looking in `self.imp().?` and I am expecting to get a reference to the `gtk::TreeView` from the CompositeTemplate parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use

```
self.imp().instance()
```